# Wrapper component for component installed via npm

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a file called checkbox.js which has the following content

```
import 'icheck/skins/all.css'
import react_icheck from 'react-icheck'

export default react_icheck
```

Why I do so because I want to reduce one line which is import 'icheck/skins/all.css' to be placed in my modules. For example I have 3 moduels : 1. products, products detail and setting, all of them used icheck, I want to avoid place import 'icheck/skins/all.css' in 3 different places. That's why I have a wrapper component called checkbox.js. But I have this error

```
./resources/assets/app/module/product.js
95:24-32 "export 'Checkbox' was not found in './common/Checkbox'
```

when I do

```
import { Checkbox, Radio } from './common/checkbox';
```

in my module.

If possible if I found another useful component (for example dropdown) I also want to put into dropdown.js, so that it's as my own global component. But first how can I solved above problem?

Comment: Because you don't have named export, you are using default one.

Comment: @dfsq named export like how? as I know react_icheck has everything?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you use export default but you have to use export
Something like this:

```
import 'icheck/skins/all.css'
import {* as react_icheck} from 'react-icheck'

export {...react_icheck}
```

Answer (score 0):

React after 0.12 we'll begin work on moving to ES6 classes. If you use an ES6 transpiler you will be able to declare your components like this:

```
class MyComponent {
  render() {
    return(

    );
  }
};
export {MyComponent};
```

or like this:

```
export class MyComponent {
  render() {
    ...
  }
};
```

Comment: you can try ur code, it won't work because I've tried.

Comment: And this `export { react_icheck };` ?

Comment: is that all? can you try to update ur answer to a full working code?